# SWT: remove the invisible component space in composite

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, composite

I put three composite(1,2,3) inside one composite0, so they all set their layout based on the  `composite0.setLayout(new FormLayout())`. The problem I have now is, I make the composite3 invisible: `composite3.setVisible(false);` (I dont want to delete the data, still need that component, but just doesn't want it shows on the UI), and there's a big gap after componite2 now. How to remove the big gap(which use to put the composite2)? thank you in advanced!

Answer (score -3, accepted):

```
        FormData data = new FormData();
        data.left = new FormAttachment(0, 100, EditorPanel.SPACING);
        data.top = new FormAttachment(section1, EditorPanel.SPACING);
        data.height = 0;
        data.width = 0;
        addSectionFormData(a, b, c);
        a.setLayoutData(data);
        b.setLayoutData(data);
```

this solve the problem! :)

Comment: Hi, could you please enhance that answer of yours. This code snippet alone doesn't do much good for someone who doesn't know your code. E.g. the class `EditorPanel`, the method `addSectionFormData()` and the variables `a`, `b` and `c`

Answer (score 1):

[Snippet 313](http://git.eclipse.org/c/platform/eclipse.platform.swt.git/tree/examples/org.eclipse.swt.snippets/src/org/eclipse/swt/snippets/Snippet313.java) of the official SWT examples should help you with that. You basically set a different `FormData` on composite3 depending on whether you want to show or hide it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply! I have question, if I set FormData to both composite1 and composite2, then delete the whole composite0.setLayout(new FormLayout()) stuff, then the whole composite0 won't show on the UI now :(

Answer (score 1):

I have a databinding observable for that, but it assumes the controls to be within a GridLayout. I use it to show and hide composites and widgets within a wizard page, depending on the selection state of a checkbox.

To use it, set it up with something like this:

```
DataBindingContext dbc = new DataBindingContext();
Button button = new Button(composite, SWT.CHECK);
IObservableValue target = SWTObservables.observeSelection(button);
dbc.bindValue(target, new HideControlObservable(someControl));
```

Here is the observable:

```java
/**
 * Observable to control the presence (visibility and size) of any control
 * within a grid layout.
 * <p>
 * Changing the value of this observable will do two things:
 * <ol>
 * <li>Set the visibility of the control</li>
 * <li>Set the size of the control to zero when the control is invisible.</li>
 * </ol>
 * So, when using this observable, the control will not only be invisible,
 * but it will be gone, completely. Normally, when setting the visibility of
 * a control to <code>false</code>, the control will not be displayed but
 * will still take all the space on the screen.
 * </p>
 * <p>
 * <strong>Note:</strong> this observable works for controls within a
 * <strong>GridLayout only</strong>.
 * </p>
 */
public class HideControlObservable extends WritableValue implements IValueChangeListener {
    private final DataBindingContext dbc = new DataBindingContext();
    private final ISWTObservableValue sizeObservable;
    private final Point size = new Point(0, 0);
    private final Control control;

    public HideControlObservable(Control control) {
        super(control.getVisible(), Boolean.class);
        this.control = control;

        UpdateValueStrategy never = new UpdateValueStrategy(UpdateValueStrategy.POLICY_NEVER);
        dbc.bindValue(SWTObservables.observeVisible(control), this, never, null);

        sizeObservable = SWTObservables.observeSize(control);
        sizeObservable.addValueChangeListener(this);

        if (!control.isVisible()) {
            GridData gd = (GridData) control.getLayoutData();
            if (gd == null) {
                gd = new GridData();
            }
            gd.exclude = true;
            control.setLayoutData(gd);
            control.setSize(new Point(0, 0));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void doSetValue(Object value) {
        super.doSetValue(value);
        Boolean bool = (Boolean) value;
        if (bool) {
            GridData gd = (GridData) control.getLayoutData();
            if (gd == null) {
                gd = new GridData();
            }
            gd.exclude = false;
            control.setLayoutData(gd);
            control.setSize(size);
            control.getParent().layout();
        } else {
            GridData gd = (GridData) control.getLayoutData();
            if (gd == null) {
                gd = new GridData();
            }
            gd.exclude = true;
            control.setLayoutData(gd);
            control.setSize(new Point(0, 0));
            control.getParent().layout();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void dispose() {
        sizeObservable.dispose();
        super.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleValueChange(ValueChangeEvent event) {
        Point newSize = (Point) event.getObservableValue().getValue();
        if (newSize.x > size.x) {
            size.x = newSize.x;
        }
        if (newSize.y > size.y) {
            size.y = newSize.y;
        }
    }
}
```